# Getting different vlan when connect with my phone with USB tethering

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb, android

I'm trying to figure this out.
I don't have the option to connect my PC to the network via ethernet and I don't have any Wi-Fi capabilities on my PC so I'm using an old smartphone with USB tethering. the phone is connected to my Wi-Fi and getting the Wi-Fi's network VLAN 192.168.1.X.
On my PC my internet is working this way but I'm getting a different VLAN 192.168.42.X. This is really problematic accessing different stuff on my network.
I've tried to change my PC IP manually but the connection stopped working.
Is there a way (android option / PC software) to make my PC (192.168.42.X) the same VLAN as my other network (192.168.1.X)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting a different VLAN, your getting a different LAN, and therefore a different subnet. This is inherent to tethering: the phone only gets one IP address on the Wifi subnet, so it can only connect your PC to the Wifi by running Network Address Translation. This requires a separate subnet.

Best solution: buy a Wifi adapter for your PC...

Comment: I guess you are right, this is the best solution. Thanks!